# Setting QObject* as QMLEngine root context property

Tags: c++, qt, qml

In my current Qt-Quick-UI-based C++ application I want to make a `QObject` with a `Q_PROPERTY(QAbstractListModel * ...)` available to my UI:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
 Q_OBJECT
 Q_PROPERTY(MyListModel* model READ model CONSTANT)
 public:
  const MyListModel* model() const {return m_model.get();}
 private:
  std::unique_ptr<MyListModel> m_model;
}
```

Based on the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html) the way I understood this should work is that in e.g. my main.cpp I do the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 std::unique_ptr<QCoreApplication> app;  // allows both console and GUI mode
 BackendController controller;  // holds a MyClass object and according (pointer-typed) getter
 std::unique_ptr<QQmlApplicationEngine> qmlengine;  // needed for GUI mode
 if(GUI_MODE)
 {
  app.reset(new QApplication(argc, argv));
  qmlengine.reset(new QQmlApplicationEngine(app));
  qmlengine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myobject", controller.getMyObject());
  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/uimain.qml")));
  auto rcontext = qmlengine->rootContext();
 } // else ...
 return app->exec();
}
```

I would expect to be able to do something like this in my QML:

```
ListView {
  id: listview
  model: myobject.model
  delegate: Text {
    text: "An entry"
  }
}
```

However, even if I ensure that there are entries in the `MyListModel`, my `ListView` stays empty. Which is the reason why I put in the `auto rcontext` line, set a breakpoint there and ran a debugger (after trying a myriad of other approaches to check why nothing displays).

When comparing the pointers of the `MyObject` stored in the `BackendController` class (and the pointer that is returned by the getter as well) to the context property that was set in `rcontext`, there is a mismatch. The debugger states that the "myobject" property I set is a `QVariant<bool>` (evaluating to `true`), and when extracting the actual stored value (i.e. what should be a `QObject*`), it differs from the pointer I passed to the `setContextProperty` function.

I noticed the same behaviour even when passing pointers from the `main()` scope, like `app.get()`, but when passing `QVariant` "primitives" (like `QString`s) they get registered without issues.

In case that this is relevant: after initializing the `QQmlApplicationEngine` and before loading the actual QML file, I also registered (uncreatable) QML types for all object types that QML may get into contact with (i.e. `MyObject` and `MyListModel`) and imported the according pseudo-module in QML as well - to no avail.

So I am now wondering what is going on here. Is this some flaw with how Qt 5.10 evaluates the `setContextProperty` function when given `QObject*`-type arguments? Or am I grossly overlooking something in my setup here?

Comment: The first step would be to store the pointer you set as `myobject` (`controller.getMyObject()`) in a `QVariant` locally and ensure that `isValid()` returns `true` for it. I can't remember if it's necessary, but you might have to construct the variant like this: `QVariant::fromValue(controller.getMyObject())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, my mistake was making the `MyClass` getter function (`controller.getMyObject()`) a `const` function. Apparently, the `setContextProperty()` function expects either some `QVariant` or an **in no way `const`** `QObject*`.